# robot is not algined to the laser scanner frame

Tags: ros, rviz, robot, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have my own URDF file, when I try to do mapping using the slam_gmapping node, then open the rviz with the map and robot model, then I can see that what the actual laser scanner is seeing is exactly 90 degree offset to how the lase scanner is oriented in the simulation.

for more details please  go through the screen shot attached:
[image: image description]

Please find my URDF here. :

```
<robot name="my_robot">

  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.6 0.35 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="white">
        <color rgba="0.2 1 0.3 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
 <link name="lwheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="base_to_lwheel" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="lwheel"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.1 -0.2 -0.025" rpy="1.5708 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="-0.1 -0.2 -0.025 " />
  </joint>

 <link name="rwheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.1"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_rwheel" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="rwheel"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.1 0.2 -0.025" rpy="-1.5708 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <link name="fwheel_left">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.03"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_fwheel_left" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="fwheel_left"/>
    <origin xyz="0.22 -0.1 -0.095" rpy="1.5708 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <link name="fwheel_right">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.05" radius="0.03"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_fwheel_right" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="fwheel_right"/>
    <origin xyz="0.22 0.1 -0.095" rpy="-1.5708 0 0"/>
  </joint>

   <link name="camera_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.28 0.065 0.04"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

   <link name="scan_support">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.36" radius="0.015"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="1 0.2 0.1 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  
  <joint name="base_to_scan_support" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="scan_support"/>
    <origin xyz="0.10 0 0.255" rpy="0 0 0"/>
 </joint>

  <joint name="base_to_scanner" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="camera_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.10 0 0.455" rpy="0 0 -1.5708"/>
 </joint>

</robot>
```

Any insights for what might be wrong here..?

Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191703/robot-is-not-algined-to-the-laser-scanner-frame/) by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-09-02**:
What is the Reference Frame in "Grid"?

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-09-02**:
The reference frame in grid was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I woud **rotate the link** between the *laser* and **your robot's body** 90 degrees on your **URDF**.

**[UPDATE]**

Yup... you have to rotate the link between the *laser* and the *robot body* by 90 degrees. See the following image:

[image: image description]

The red line (x direction) of the *camera_link* is pointing to the right side of the robot. It should be pointing to the front!

Try changing this in your URDF

```
...


<link name="camera_link">
  <visual>
    <geometry>
      <box size="0.065 0.28 0.04"/>
    </geometry>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <material name="black">
      <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>

...

<joint name="base_to_scanner" type="fixed">
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="camera_link"/>
  <origin xyz="0.10 0 0.455" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-09-03**:
But ideally this should be done..?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-09-03**:
Well, according to your screen shot the fixed frame is set to *map* and all the other frames seem to be correct. To me that suggests that there is a mistake on the URDF link tree. Could you post the URDF file?

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-09-03**:
martin, I have modified the question with the URDF, can you please re-visit the question again.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-09-03**:
sumanth, I think I've found your problem. Please see the updated answer for the solution

**Comment by [sumanth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18196/sumanth/) on 2014-09-03**:
Martin, Many thanks
super help, I have over looked the coordinate frame of my scanner.
thanks